# Properly dispose of non referenced Image without garbage collection C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have a C# program which creates a List of Bitmaps from the images in a directory. It'll use the whole list of Bitmaps to generate one new image, which it will then save. When the user loads a new directory to repeat the process, the List of Bitmaps is cleared and refilled. The bitmaps are loaded upon creation of the object, "new Bitmap(path)".

I had a problem which occurred when the user performed the following steps:

1. Load images from directory 1
2. Chose not to save and instead load images from directory 2
3. Tries to save by overwriting an image from directory 1
4. Program is unable to save due to "A generic error in GDI+", because it is still "using" the image that is being overwritten.

The original List of Bitmaps loaded from directory 1 is indeed cleared and then refilled with images from directory 2. However, Bitmap.Save() refuses to overwrite an image it had previously loaded *unless* I call System.GC.Collect() after I perform Clear().

I'm pretty sure the problem has something to do with keeping the Bitmaps around even though there are no references, otherwise why would garbage collecting solve the problem? Is this the right way to go about solving this problem, or is there a "proper" way to dispose of Bitmaps in C#? Thanks.

Comment: Are you loading them via `Bitmap.FromStream`? How are you "disposing" of them currently? By calling `.Dispose()`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not; I'm using new Bitmap(path). Let me update the question.

Comment: I'm not calling .Dispose(); for some reason that didn't come to mind. Oh jeez, sorry for the stupid question. I guess I'll just answer it myself... unless you want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Dispose` on the `Bitmap` instances.. so they free their file handle.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(path_to_file);
// use it
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Or, since `Bitmap` inherits from `Image` which implements `IDisposable`, you can do this:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(path_to_file)) {
    // use it..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I forgot about that. I even used the word "dispose" in the title.